# Read all files in a folder then place each file and its match in new excel document. Is it possible with C++?

Tags: c++, export-to-excel

I have a folder that contains 300 different files. There are 150 .cft files and 150 .s01 files. Each .cft file has a corresponding .s01 file of the same name. I would like to create a program that can read the files from the folder and place each .cft file and its corresponding .s01 file into an excel document. I would like the .cft file to be on the first worksheet in the document and the .s01 file to be on the second sheet. Then I would like the program to save the file and name it (---------).xls. The (---------) would be the name of the .cft and .s01 file since they are both the same.

So!!! I wrote a program that is able to take the .cft file and the .s01 file, append them and place them in a user defined .xls document. However...I don't want to manually get the names of the 150 files and have to type each one into the program. I also don't want the files to be placed on the same worksheet.

So!!!! I don't want to waste time trying to code something impossible, so before I spend anymore time on this I have a few questions:

1. Is it possible to read all of the files in a folder and match files of the same name but with different types?
2. If this is possible, is it then possible to place the corresponding .cft file and .s01 file in the same excel document but on different worksheets?
3. Then, is it possible to create and save this worksheet as (---------).xls, (-------) being the name of the matching .cft and .s01 file?

So basically...I want to write this code because I am lazy and I don't want to do anything manually ><;;; lol

**Example:**

1. The main folder contains 8 files:

   dog.cft dog.s01 cat.cft cat.s01 tree.cft tree.s01 bird.cft bird.s01
2. The program reads all of the files in the folder and recognizes that dog.cft and dog.s01 go together.
3. The program then creates an excel document and on worksheet 1 places dog.cft and on worksheet 2 places dog.s01.
4. The program then saves the excel document as dog.xls
5. Then the program loops through the main folder repeating this process for each of the .cft and .s01 pairs until all 150 pairs have been separated and saved in their own excel document.

I don't know if I'm dreaming a little too big with this but any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: "Is X possible with C++?" For any task X which computers are capable of doing, the answer is Yes.

Comment: Well I know that it is possible through the use of C++, however, my question is regarding the ability to complete the task without manually entering file names.

Answer (score 3):

personally I would do this with a macro in excel rather than in c++ because doing excel related functions is much easier that way. All of the requirements are possible using VBA within excel.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not familiar with VBA at all and I'm just beginning C++. 
But would you say that what I'm trying to do is indeed possible using VBA?

Comment: yes very much so, interfacing with an excel file is much easier in VBA than C++.

Comment: @Jessica VBA is a horrible language though (subjective yes, but still) and Interop between managed code (say managed c++/c#) works quite well. So that is one possibility as well. Actually C++ and COM isn't that hard either - the boilerplate code necessary for communication with Excel exists all over the net.

Comment: oh I agree, VBA makes me shudder, but I feel in this case it's probably easier to complete this task using VBA especially as the poster claims to be new to C++

Comment: Well, I'm doing this as a "fun" project outside of school. I remember how much I hated having to copy and paste files into excel, so that's my motive for creating this program. Even though it may be "easier" with VBA, I'd like to complete this with C++ because I believe it would be good practice. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

For the listing of files in a folder, you can use the Windows API functions [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When you finish iterating the folder, you'll need to call [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For creating the Excel spreadsheet and working with the workbook's sheets, you can use COM automation. Here's a [link to an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141759) on doing so from C++ (MFC); the article explains where to find one that isn't MFC based.

If you get started and have specific questions about either of the tasks, please post them as separate questions. This should have been two individual questions, in fact - one about iterating the content of a folder and a different one about working with Excel files from C++.

Comment: Though VBA is the way to go for almost any simple task...if one insists on using C++ then even easier than COM automation is to have the C++ program spit out comma-delimited files (or similar) and then load those into Excel.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-HP010014103.aspx#BMtextformats

Comment: True, but that wasn't the question. :) Also, you'd have to spit out two synchronized files and load them individually (because the question asked about putting them on separate worksheets).

Comment: Well, I wrote a program that is able to append user-defined files to a  single worksheet within a user-defined .xls document. And everything is working well with the comma-delimited files. I am just wanting to cut out the manual entry of the file names.

Comment: @Jessica, I gave you info on doing that in the second paragraph of my answer. In fact, I answered #'s 2, 3, and 4 of your numbered list.

Comment: @KenWhite, I just read about FindFirstFile, when you use this function do you have to give the program a file name to find? I am not quite understanding how the function works. But I want to be able to just give the program a folder and no other information, and it will take the folder and read the files that it contains without the user giving it a specific file name to find.

Comment: @Jessica, you can use wildcards, so you can look in folder `C:\Data` for files ending with `.cft` by using `C:\Data\*.cft` as the folder and file specification. For each file found, you look for the corresponding `.so1` file, and if both are found you write them to the spreadsheet (or `.csv` or whatever). As I said though, if you have specific questions about either of the things you asked about here, you should post them as *separate* new questions.

Comment: Okay! This really helps a lot! I'm going to try and figure out the FindFirstFile and I'll split this question into two ^^ Thank you!

Comment: @Jessica, a search here on `[c++] FindFirstFile` finds several matches that might help.